# passing id of element with button PHP

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I develope a kind of gambling site for a friend of me.
For this a user can enter an amount he would like to bet. After this he clicks one of 81 images. Now I would need to get the "id" which box was clicked and I need to get the value he entered to bit.

Here's a screenshot of the game itself:
[image: gambling]

How to design the forms?
I tried to use this, but after some thinking it won't make sense:

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ action('Utility\PlayController@getPlay') }}">
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount"></label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-btc"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="11" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" value="0.00010000">
              </div>
          </div>
          </br>
         @for ($i = 1; $i <= 81; $i++)
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$i}}">    
          <input type="image" name="submit" src="<?=asset('assets/img/box_closed.png')?>" border="0" alt="{{$i}}" />
         @endfor
  </form>
```

All in all when the POST request is send I need to get the value entered in the field above AND the id of the box user clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit on clicking a box, simply make the input type="submit", and set the name and value appropriately then you

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ action('Utility\PlayController@getPlay') }}">
      {!! csrf_field() !!}
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount"></label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-btc"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="11" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" value="0.00010000">
          </div>
      </div>
      </br>
     @for ($i = 1; $i <= 81; $i++)
      <input class="box-input" type="submit" name="id" value="{{$i}}">
      <img class="box-input-image" src="{{ asset('assets/img/box_closed.png') }}">
     @endfor
</form>
```

This will place an image there so you need to make box-input hidden in your CSS using display:none or whatever. Or you could just use the :after psuedo CSS selector

Comment: I would like to submit the "form" by clicking on a box, that's why I would like to use this way.

Comment: Could you please provide me a short code preview, so I may understand?

Comment: added code sample, it's just what you wrote exactly but just with the input as a submit that you need to style yourself

Comment: But how to include now a picture and make the id hidden, so user just see the picture, not the text with the ID?

Comment: as i said in the answer just style it using CSS, something like using the after psuedo selector. alternatively, just set the display to none for the box input, then include an img tag in the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
**use radio button behind image box using css
or 
in image box set there (alt) as value then on click on image

<img src="1.jpg" height="150" onclick="setCookie(this.alt)" value="1" alt="1">
<script>
function setCookie(val)
{
document.cookie = "whichBoxIsClicked="+val;
}
</script>
//get that cookie anywhere**
```

Comment: without usage of javascript.

Comment: bro you need a submit form with submit button or javascript to submit form no any other ways to submit it